# Exposing CDI beans from Quarkus extensions

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to implement a Quarkus extension which based on runtime configuration provides a SecurityIdentityAugmentor.

deployment:

MyProcessor

```
@Record(ExecutionTime.RUNTIME_INIT)
@BuildStep 
private MyMarkerConfiguredBuildItem setupAugmentor(MyRecorder recorder, MyAugmentorConfig config, BeanContainerBuildItem beanContainer) {
    recorder.sertConfig(config, beanContainer.getValue();
    return new MyMarkerConfiguredBuildItem ();
}
```

runtime:

1. MyRecorder:

```
public void setConfig(MyAugmentorConfig config, BeanContainer beanContainer) {
    beanContainer.instance(MyProducer.class).setConfig(config);
}
```

2. MyProducer :

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyProducer {

    public void setConfig(MyConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public MyAugmentor createAugmentor() {
        return new MyAugmentor(this.config);
    }
}
```

The only way I can get MyAugmentor instance produced in my client application is by adding a beans.xml in the extension's runtime module. However I don't  see beans.xml in other extensions in the github repo. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think producing an `AdditionalBeanBuildItem` for the `MyProducer` class might help. Not exactly sure, but worth a try.

Comment: @Ladicek, I actually gave it a try - can't really use it since the  configuration is only available at runtime. AdditionalBuildItem tries to instantiate the MyAugmentor  using a default constructor since the producer is not yet known.

Comment: @Ranjan `AdditionalBeanBuildItem` will not instantiate your `MyAugmentor` class and you don't need a recorder for this as you can inject your config inside your producer.
I try to wrote some example.

Comment: @loicmathieu, you are right. I think the problem was the recorder setup which as you correctly pointed out I didn't need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a build step to register your producer bean (as it will not be automatically discovered because extensions are not indexed) inside the deployment module of your extension:

```
@BuildStep
public AdditionalBeanBuildItem producer() {
    return new AdditionalBeanBuildItem(MyProducer.class);
}
```

The producer must be in the runtime module of your extension, you can inject your configuration inside it.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyProducer {

    @Inject MyConfig config;

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public MyAugmentor createAugmentor() {
        return new MyAugmentor(this.config);
    }
}
```

This construct is used in a lot of existing extensions, you can see for exemple my Firestore extension here: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-google-cloud-services/tree/master/firestore