# UnsatisfiedResolutionException - CDI beans from Quarkus extensions

Tags: cdi, javabeans, quarkus

I'm working on a Quarkus Extension. But I have some problems to inject CDI Beans.

In the runtime module I have this class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomRestClientBuilder{

    //@Produces - Removed
    //@ApplicationScoped - Removed
    public RestClientBuilder newBuilder(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
         return RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().baseUrl(new URL(url));               
    }
}
```

In the deployment module, I have this class:

```
class RestClientExtensionProcessor {

    private static final String FEATURE = "rest-client-extension";

    @BuildStep
    FeatureBuildItem feature() {
        return new FeatureBuildItem(FEATURE);
    }
    
    @BuildStep
    public AdditionalBeanBuildItem producer() {
        return new AdditionalBeanBuildItem(CustomRestClientBuilder.class);
    }

}
```

And the problem appears in testing classes. I put the Test in Deployment module and it fails (however, in runtime module it works).

```
public class CustomRestClientBuilderTest {

      @Inject
      private CustomRestClientBuilder customRest;
      
      @RegisterExtension
      static final QuarkusUnitTest config = new QuarkusUnitTest()
        .setArchiveProducer(() -> ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)); 
    
      @Test
      public void testGreeting() {
            IDummyRestClient restClient = customRest.newBuilder("url")
                .build(IDummyRestClient.class);
      }
}
```

The error is:

```
Build failed due to errors
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: 
javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: 
Unsatisfied dependency for type CustomRestClientBuilder and qualifiers [@Default]
```

I've checked this post before:

[Exposing CDI beans from Quarkus extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105784/exposing-cdi-beans-from-quarkus-extensions)

**UPDATED**

This way is working (adding the class I need for testing). **Does it makes sense?**

```
@RegisterExtension
static final QuarkusUnitTest config = new QuarkusUnitTest()
   .setArchiveProducer(() -> ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
   .addClasses(CustomRestClientBuilder.class, 
               IDummyRestClient.class));
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: `AdditionalBeanBuildItem` lets you make the bean unremovable, can you try that?

Comment: I've tried with this, but unfortunately it doesn't work:
    @BuildStep
    public AdditionalBeanBuildItem producer() {
      AdditionalBeanBuildItem.Builder beanBuild = AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder();
      beanBuild.addBeanClass(CustomRestClientBuilder.class);
      beanBuild.setUnremovable();
      return beanBuild.build();
    }

Comment: Did you try injecting `RestClientBuilder` instead of `CustomRestClientBuilder`?

Comment: Hi @geoand, the error is the same: "Unsatisfied dependency for type org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.RestClientBuilder and qualifiers". Anyway, I need a "custom" RestClientBuilder implementation. Thx for your comment.

Comment: Umm, one more thing: why does the `newBuilder` method have the `@Produces` and `@ApplicationScoped` annotations? It is not a valid producer method (I'm pretty sure you don't have a bean of type `String` anywhere).

Comment: You are right. I don't need anything different that a Custom Bean and use it in the tests. If I test in the runtime side, it works. But in the deployment side it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, I've updated with an approach that it works now, I don't know if it makes sense. Thanks